# Interesting observations of argc, argv, and its usage

Tags: c, linux, pointers, argv

So, I am working on a Linux based command line utility, that has to accept a few flags, and I have noticed some interesting behavior.  I will be posting testing code that I was using outside of the main utility.  I was using this code, so I did not have to alter the actual utility until I had working code that I could just insert.  So here is the code that I have been fiddling with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    while(--argc && (*++argv)[0] == '-') 
        putchar('*');

    printf("\n%s\n", argv[0]);
 }
```

Please ignore the fact that all this program does is print an asterisk and print its own name when invoked with one argument -b.  The printing of the asterik was just to show that the loop ran once.  So, I run this in a terminal as "./test -n", and I expected the output to be:

*./test

Much to my surprise, the output was:

*-b

I have a working theory of what the statement 
`(*++argv)[0]` is doing, but I am still a little hazy on it.  My assumption is that it steps across the array of pointers looking at the first character in each string pointed to, `(*++argv)[0]` is now dereferencing `*argv[0]` or element zero of the first argument string.

So, basically I have three questions:

1. What exactly is that statement doing?
2. Why can I not get back to argv[0] or argv[0][0], no matter what I try?
3. Is storing the value at the address pointed to by argv[0] in another char *, this is the only way that I have been able to access that value at this point, the normal way around this?

I am really confounded by this at the moment and have tried everything that I can think of to work this out. At one point I had a loop that would print the alphabet, I don't know what part of memory the program was accessing. The most interesting permutation was pulling sshid variables from somewhere.

Thank you all in advance for your help with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`++argv` changes `argv` to point to the next argument.

Try something like

```
int i = 0;
while(--argc && argv[++i][0] == '-')
```

Which maintains a separate index, instead of overwriting `argv`.

Or

```
char** argp = argv;
while(--argc && (*++argp)[0] == '-')
```

which works the same as the original, except it changes a copy of `argv` instead of the original.

Comment: So then my assuptions were correct.  Is this a common thing?  I have not run into this before.

Comment: It is just the semantics of incrementing an array pointer in *C*. It has nothing specific with program argument passing.

Comment: I'd say that this is fairly common usage. Not quite a ubiquitous as for(i=0; i<SOMEVAL; i++), but definitely often used in argument parsing or when working with strings of strings in some other context.

Comment: Basile, I have seen getopt, however its use is outside of my abilites at the moment.  I am trying to teach myself C, and I am writing small to medium sized programs to do that.  This current exercise was more or less intended to learn some of the more subtle aspects of capturing arguments, as well as pointers, and some of the more complex aspects of pointers as well.  I am sure that I will be back when I start trying to grasp the concept of pointers to functions, and pointers to structures.